# How to use wildcard character in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

SELECT * from TB_PETS where PET_NAME like '_[ali]%';

Why this code is not working? Im trying to list all the record that has second character is a, l, i but it doesn'y work.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
SELECT * from TB_PETS where PET_NAME like '_ali%';
```

it should give you what you want

```
with TB_PETS as (
select 'Kalito' as PET_NAME from dual union all
select 'Maline' from dual union all
select 'Kumpara' from dual
)
SELECT * from TB_PETS where PET_NAME like '_ali%';

PET_NAME
Kalito
Maline
```

Answer (score 0):

Finds any values that have "r" in the second position

```
WHERE columnName LIKE '_r%'
```

More details visit this link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp